# Why do we need the alternative definition `nested-name-specifier identifier ::` in the definition of the grammar production `nested-name-specifier`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, grammar

The definition of a *[nested-name-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#qual)* includes the alternative definition

*nested-name-specifier* *identifier* `::`

Why is this necessary?

Comment: How else do you make `A::B::C::D::` a *nested-name-specifier*?

Comment: @T.C. It's so obvious now. Sorry for the silly question.